# Orika map fields from a list of objects to a list

Tags: java, list, mapper, orika

I'm using Orika and
I have following classes:

```
public class A {
    private B b1;
    private B b2;
}

public class B {
    //other fields
}

public class C {
    List<D> ds;
}

public class D {
    private Object o;
}

public class E {
    List<A> as;
}

public class F {
    List<C> cs;
}
```

and I want to map E to F, but all objects of A should be mapped to C (in object o)..
so when I map **as** with (2 objects of **A**) to **cs** it should contain 4 objects of C (with the value of A in Object o)..

Thanks in advance

I did an attempt:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(E.class, F.class)
        .field("as{b1}","cs{o}")
        .field("as{b2}","cs{o}")
        .byDefault().register();
```

but now only b2 is saved in o.. So b1 is overridden